# XSL Transformation through code does not result in the same output as XSL transformation done through a tool

Tags: .net, frameworks, xslcompiledtransform

I am transforming my XML file to another XML file using the XslCompiledTransform classes available in the .NET framework 3.5

Here's my code.

```
private static void transformUtil(string sXmlPath, string sXslPath, string outputFileName)
    {
        try
        {

            XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument(sXmlPath);
            XslCompiledTransform myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
            //load the Xsl 
            myXslTrans.Load(sXslPath);
            //create the output stream
            XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter(outputFileName, null);
            //do the actual transform of Xml
            myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc, null, myWriter);
            myWriter.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            EventLogger eventLog;
            eventLog = new EventLogger("transformUtil", e.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

The code works, but the output file does not have the XML declaration in the header.

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>**
```

I am at a loss to understand this. When I use the same XSL file to transform the XML, using a tool like notepad++ or visual studio, the transformation contains the XML declaration in the header. So is XslCompiledTransform responsible for truncating this declaration? I am puzzled.

Anyone else facing similar issues?

My XSL file header looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
```

Comment: For some reason the XSL file is getting truncated.
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">

Answer (score 1):

The XML writer used does not have any settings associated with it.

**change**

```
//create the output stream
XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter(outputFileName, null);
```

**to**

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = 
   new XmlWriterSettings
   {
      OmitXmlDeclaration = false
   };
XmlWriter myWriter = XmlWriter.Create(outputFileName, settings);
```

---

Alternatively, you could do less to setup the transform:

```
private static void transformUtil(string sXmlPath, string sXslPath, 
                                  string outputFileName)
{
    try
    {
       XslCompiledTransform xsl = new XslCompiledTransform();

       // Load the XSL
       xsl.Load(sXslPath);

       // Transform the XML document
       xsl.Transform(sXmlPath, outputFileName);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       // Handle exception
    }

}
```

This should also honor the [xsl:output](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_output.asp) instructions from the XSLT file itself, in particular the `omit-xml-declaration` attribute, for which the default value is "no" if left unspecified.